# Progress openedge using embed .NET controls

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Can someone point me in the right direction of how to use embed .NET controls into a progress application. thanks!!

edit: I'm using 10.2b

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do any .NET programming with OpenEdge, I highly recommend that you start with the excellent video series from John Sadd that covers exactly this.  In fact, I recommend that you go through these videos BEFORE you even bother to start reading any of the manuals (and there are a bunch!) that Progress provides.

Run - don't walk - to http://communities.progress.com/pcom/docs/DOC-101140 and start watching!

Hope this helps (I know it will!)